# How to create a multi-line plot title in bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

How do you create a multiline plot title in bokeh?... same question as https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/994
Is this resolved yet?

```
import bokeh.plotting as plt

plt.output_file("test.html")
plt.text(x=[1,2,3], y = [0,0,0], text=['hello\nworld!', 'hello\nworld!', 'hello\nworld!'], angle = 0)
plt.show()
```

Additionally, can the title text string accept rich text?

Answer (score 13):

The answer below is still correct and applicable if you want to have multiple styles for title/subtitles, etc. However, if you only need multiple lines with a single style, then in recent version of Bokeh you can simply include newlines directly in the title text:

```py
p = figure(title="a title\nnext line")
```

[image]

---

OLDER ANSWER:

For multi-line titles, you will can add explicit `Title` annotations for each line you want. Here is a complete example:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import Title
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("test.html")

p = figure(x_range=(0, 5))
p.text(x=[1,2,3], y = [0,0,0], text=['hello\nworld!', 'hello\nworld!', 'hello\nworld!'], angle = 0)

p.add_layout(Title(text="Sub-Title", text_font_style="italic"), 'above')
p.add_layout(Title(text="Title", text_font_size="16pt"), 'above')

show(p)
```

Which produces:

[image]

Note that you are limited to the standard "text properties" that Bokeh exposes, since the underlying HTML Canvas does not accept rich text. If you need something like that it might be possible with a [custom extension](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can add a simple title to your plot with this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

output_file("test.html")
p = figure(title="Your title")
p.text(x=[1,2,3], y = [0,0,0], text=['hello\nworld!', 'hello\nworld!', 'hello\nworld!'], angle = 0)
show(p)
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**

Here is a working example for plotting a pandas dataframe for you to copy/paste into a jupyter notebook. It's neither elegant nor pythonic. I got it a long time ago from various SO posts. Sorry, that I don't remember which ones anymore, so I can't cite them.

**Code**

```
# coding: utf-8
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Create some data
np_arr = np.array([[1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3], [4,4,4]])
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np_arr)
pd_df

# Convert for multi-line plotting
data = [row[1].as_matrix() for row in pd_df.iterrows()]
num_lines = len(pd_df)
cols = [pd_df.columns.values] * num_lines
data

# Init bokeh output for jupyter notebook - Adjust this to your needs
output_notebook()

# Plot
p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300)
p.multi_line(xs=cols, ys=data)
show(p)
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: Question asks for a multi-line plot title.