# How can I achieve a multiline title for a holoviews plot?

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I would like more than one line as an option for a title of a holoviews plot object.  Only strings are allowed, and it seems what works for a print statement does not work for a title.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
from holoviews import opts

plot_title = 'Line 1 \nLine 2'
plot_title
# printing results in two lines, the \n is recognized
print(plot_title)

# the \n is ignored when the string is used for a title
points = [(0.1*i, np.sin(0.1*i)) for i in range(100)]
hv.Curve(points).opts(title=plot_title)
```

[image: simple plot]

Answer (score 4):

`HoloViews` uses `bokeh` as a plotting backend in your example and this feature, i.e multi-line title, isn't supported yet by `bokeh`. Note that your question is similar to this one: [How to create a multi-line plot title in bokeh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666717/how-to-create-a-multi-line-plot-title-in-bokeh) and that there is now (27/04/2020) a related open issue on bokeh https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7317.

I see two ways of getting multilines title for your plot.

The first one is adapted from the other SO question and makes use of bokeh directly to add titles as a layout:

```py
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
import bokeh.io
from bokeh.models import Title
hv.extension('bokeh')

points = [(0.1*i, np.sin(0.1*i)) for i in range(100)]

hv_curve = hv.Curve(points)
bk_curve = hv.render(hv_curve)
bk_curve.add_layout(Title(text="Sub-Title", text_font_style="italic"), 'above')
bk_curve.add_layout(Title(text="Title", text_font_size="16pt", text_font_style="bold"), 'above')
bokeh.io.show(bk_curve)
```

[image: bokeh solution]

The second one makes use of [`panel`](https://panel.holoviz.org/) (a dependency of `HoloViews` now) to display the titles as two Markdown panes (it could also be one HTML pane) both centered in a `Column` layout above the curve:

```py
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

points = [(0.1*i, np.sin(0.1*i)) for i in range(100)]

hv_curve = hv.Curve(points)
panel_layout pn.Column(
    pn.pane.Markdown("**Title**", align="center"),  # bold
    pn.pane.Markdown("*Sub-title*", align="center"),  # italic
    hv_curve
)
panel_layout
```

[image: panel solution]

If you run `panel_layout.pprint()` you'll be able to check the structure of that layout.

```
Column
    [0] Markdown(str, align='center')
    [1] Markdown(str, align='center')
    [2] HoloViews(Curve)
```

Note: Run with `Holoviews 1.13.2`, `bokeh 2.0.1` and `panel 0.9.5`.

Comment: Thanks!  The point that bokeh doesn't do multi-line - that was my suspicion. I figured there was just some syntax issue I missed.  I note that the first example does not specify exactly where the text should go - that one appears above the other happens becoase of the 'above' argument?

Comment: Yes you can see in the bokeh docs [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html) that the ``add_layout`` method allows to declare where you want to add the ``Title``. In the example I add first the subtitle above the plot, then the title above the subtitle.

Comment: In the first example, to make it work, the import `from bokeh.models import Title` is needed for the Title call.